# MUI Autocomplete stretches buttons and breakes layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I'm using MUI library with React. I'm using Autocomplete with TextInput to create input fields with select box functionality. But when user enters some value, autocomplete component stretches its buttons and changes layout to vertical so the popup button actually popped out from borders of the component. How can it be fixed? What I'm doing wrong?

Here is my project dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.39",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.2",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.3",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.9",
    "material-ui-phone-number-2": "^1.3.0"
  },
```

That's how I'm using Autocomplete and TextInput

```
<Autocomplete
                style={{width: '50%'}}
                disablePortal
                id={'test-complete'}
                options={['one', 'two', 'three']}
                value={undefined}
                isOptionEqualToValue={(option: string, value: string|null) => option === value}
                renderInput={(params) =>
                    <TextField {...params}
                               label={'test-complete'}
                    />}
            />
```

And that's how it look like in browser:

1. [Before selecting value (everything is good)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs03I.png)
2. [After entering value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK7WX.png)

I've tried to change versions of libraries and also created simple test project to use only Autocomplete as I thought that problem could be in styles of outer scope components. But it didn't help.